# Efficient way to find a substring in dataset from a list of strings

Tags: r

I have a list of strings and I'm trying to find if a particular column in a dataset has that string. If yes, write that string adjacent to it.

For eg.

```
    name<-c("Ann","Brit","Cathy","Debra","Mike","Ram")
    brand_detail<-c("Reebok size 10","Nike loafers","Reebok slipper","United Colors of Benetton Shoes","Reebok size 8", "Puma slipper")

data1<- data.frame(name,brand_detail)

brand_list<-c("Reebok", "Nike", "United Colors of Benetton")
```

I am using a combination of for loop & apply function. But the loop is too inefficient and takes huge processing time as the dataset I have huge

```
data1$brand_match<-""
for(i in 1:length(brand_list))

{
  B <- function(x){grepl(brand_list[i],ignore.case = TRUE,x)}
  data1$brand_match[which(lapply(data1$brand_detail,B)=="TRUE")]<-brand_list[i]
}
```

Is there a way to use nested apply function or some more efficient way?

Comment: Nested apply sounds nasty and definitely not needed here. A function such as `gsub` or `str_extract` from `stringr` should do the job. For example `stringr::str_extract(data1$brand_detail, paste(brand_list, collapse = '|'))`

Comment: `stri_detect()` FTW